# Changing system, new problems gtk.h not found

Tags: ros, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to compile one file, that compiles fine in hydro, and gtk 2.0, but now the system as been upgraded to indigo, the file seems to compile but doesn't find gtk.h, I have gtk2.0 and gtk3.0 on my system, and I already compiled with gtk 2.0, no problems. My problem seems to be the catkin files. Can anyone give me a hand, pls.

CMakefile.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(myVideoImageSubscriber)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  sensor_msgs
)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV)

pkg_check_modules(gtk REQUIRED gtk+-2.0)
pkg_check_modules(OpenCV REQUIRED opencv)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Bost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_CFLAGS}
  ${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${GTK_CFLAGS}
)

add_executable(myvideoimagesubscriber src/myVideoImageSubscriber.cpp)

add_dependencies(myvideoimagesubscriber cv_bridge roscpp std_msgs image_transport sensor_msgs)

target_link_libraries(myvideoimagesubscriber
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
   ${GTK_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Thank's in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242227/changing-system,-new-problems-gtk.h-not-found./) by [Rodrigo Lourenço](https://answers.ros.org/users/27752/rodrigo-louren%C3%A7o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-23**:
Doesn't `pkg_check_modules(..)` store the contents of the `.pc` file it parses in the variable named by the first argument to it? So in your case `gtk`? CMake is case-sensitive, so I would expect all your `GTK_*` references later on to refer to non-existent variables then ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-23**:
Also: when posting `CMakeLists.txt`, please remove all the boilerplate comments from them (lines starting with `#`).

Finally: can you check `GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS` actually contains anything? Add something like

```
message(STATUS "GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

to your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved, it's quite simple.

First: change GTK to GTK2
Second: add this line -
find_package(GTK2 COMPONENTS gtk)

---

Originally posted by [Rodrigo Lourenço](https://answers.ros.org/users/27752/rodrigo-louren%C3%A7o/) with karma: 61 on 2016-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0